# Wordpress implode & wp_insert_post question

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields, wp-insert-post

Just a few days ago I've started working on my new wordpress based website.

I have a plugin which provides a Cars Database. I want to auto-fill my custom fields and taxonomies by taking info from this plugin.

So, I've created a custom function in functions.php. I put an ID from car's database plugin and my function autofills my fields when I PUBLISH or UPDATE the post (wp_insert_post). Everything seems to be working fine but...

In my function, I have this code:

```
if ( isset( $cardet['marks'] ) )
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, implode(', ', $cardet["marks"]), 'mark' );
```

What does this function do? It simply gets 3-4 different car marks from $cardet['marks'] and implodes it. This is required only for taxonomies.

**So, after I click publish or update the post:**

This is OK, this is how it looks like in "post edit" page. Created 3 different terms.

[image: works fine]

And this is my problem. When I go to my taxonomy page, I got this: 
It created just one term:

[image: only 1 term, why?]

I really need your help. I need to have different terms. Can't find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) takes an array, integer, or string.

> (*array/int/string*)
>   (*required*) The slug or id of the term (such as category or tag
>   IDs), will replace all existing related terms in this taxonomy. To
>   clear or remove all terms from an object, pass an empty string or
>   NULL. Integers are interpreted as tag IDs. **Warning:** some
>   functions may return term_ids as strings which will be interpreted as
>   slugs consisting of numeric characters!

You create an array (`$cardet["marks"]`) but then `implode()` it. When you `implode()` it you turn that array into a comma separated string, which `wp_set_object_terms()` interprets as a single value. `wp_set_object_terms()` will not break the string on commas and create multiple terms for you, but the solution is simple as you've added a step that is breaking things. Remove that step and pass the array to `wp_set_object_terms()`.

```
if ( isset( $cardet['marks'] ) )
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cardet["marks"], 'mark' );
```

There is sample code in the Codex doing exactly this, but with IDs:

```
// An array of IDs of categories we want this post to have.
$cat_ids = array( 6, 8 );

/*
 * If this was coming from the database or another source, we would need to make sure
 * these where integers:

$cat_ids = array_map( 'intval', $cat_ids );
$cat_ids = array_unique( $cat_ids );

 */

$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( 42, $cat_ids, 'category' );
```

If `$cardet["marks"]` is user supplied data please [sanitize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) it before using it.

Comment: That worked!That's so simple lol. Why didn't I thought about it my self? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Implode turns your array like this `array( 'Audi', 'BMW', 'Mercedes-Benz' )` into a string separated by the delimiter set in the first parameter of the function, in this case `,` a comma and a space. In a way you can turn an array into a CSV from this. The result is this: `Audi, BMW, Mercedes-Benz`.

The way WordPress works, it looks for an existing term (within that taxonomy) and if none exists it creates a new one...

In the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) it says that the terms can be provided as an array, integer or string, however I think the integer and string options may be for adding a single term at a time, I don't think it will re-explode the string, and more importantly this is a pointless process of imploding and exploding an array when it takes an array anyway and thats what you have in your `$cardet['marks']` variable.